# Where to put paperclip models and migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, paperclip

I'm having trouble integrating the model and migrations to my code as I'm not too sure *where* to put it.

I learned Rails from upskillcourses, so I only learned to mix it in with user accounts, which won't be necessary for my website. Is there a file or a directory I need to create so that I'll be able to upload pictures on multiple pages (homepage, about page, donation page) instead of just one?

Comment: Your question isn't a good fit for SO. I'd recommend doing more tutorials and research and trying things. Then ask a specific question about your code.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily as you can add it to the database.

Referring to [the Paperclip documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#models) you need to at least:

1. add the gem to your gemfile and run `bundle install`
2. add a new column to the desired model
3. add `has_attached_file` and `validates_attachment_content_type` to the model

The [usage section](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#usage) of the documentation also provides steps to implement this.

Comment: Step 2 involves `rails g migration add_x_column` where you create a migration that adds the columns.